# visualworks - how to redraw image?

Tags: image, visualworks

I have GUI with images displaying, but when I minimize or move an applciation window, the image is remvoed....how do I call it back, or how to prevent it? somehow redraw of an widget destroys it?

Answer (score 0):

you could press the middle mouse-key in order to open a menu where you can click on refresh. This should refresh your window and redraw everything in there. You can use it to debug when your image is drawn and maybe find out why you don't see anything.
But in general a little more information would be neat.